# mic-recorder-to-mp3 is not working for mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, redux

i am trying to implement audio recording for the web and mobile both and have used mic-recorder-to-mp3 this library for audio recording ,it worked well for desktop browser but not working for the android and ios mobile browsers. Its not giving any error and tried different libraries but doesnt worked for me.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mic-recorder-to-mp3
used this library

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MicRecorder from 'mic-recorder-to-mp3';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state={
   recorder: new MicRecorder({ bitRate: 128 }),
   record: true,
   currentAudio: "",
   currentAudioObject: "",
   currentAudioName: '',
   currentAudioExtension: 'mp3',
   isRecording: false,
   recordAudio: false
  }
 }

 startRecording = () => {
  this.setState({
   record: true
  });
 }

  stopRecording = () => {
   this.state.recorder
   .stop()
   .getMp3()
   .then(([buffer, blob]) => {
    this.setState({ record: false });
    const file = new File(buffer, 'Recorded_audio.mp3', {
      type: blob.type,
      lastModified: Date.now(),
    });
    let src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    this.setState(prev => {
      prev.currentAudio = src;
      prev.currentAudioObject = file;
      prev.currentAudioName = 'Recorded_audio';
      prev.currentAudioExtension = 'mp3';
      prev.isRecording = true;
      prev.recordAudio = true;
      return prev;
    });
  });
 };

 startRecorder(){
  this.state.recorder
  .start()
  .then(() => {
   this.setState({ record: true });
  })
  .catch(e => {
   console.error(e);
 });
}
 render() {
   return (
    <div className="App">
     {this.state.record ? null:<audio
      controls
       src={this.state.currentAudio}>
        Your browser does not support the
        <code>audio</code> element.
      </audio>}
      <a
        className="App-link"
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        onClick={this.startRecorder.bind(this)}
      >
        Rec
      </a>
      <button onClick={this.stopRecording} 
      type="button">Stops</button>
  </div>
 );
 }
 }

 export default App;
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use ogg base64 files

Example base64 ogg audio file.

```
data:application/ogg;base64
```